# Different network and classic Load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing

What is different between network load balancer and classic load balancer? I want to migrate my AWS architecture from classic load balancer to network load balancer. But, after some research, I think its pretty much same. The only difference is that network load balancer can have elastic IP. The different, is it only just that?

Comment: I wouldn’t say it is only just that. I’m not sure if it can be explained any better than Amazon has already: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/introduction.html if there is a question about particular features maybe you should ask about that, or describe your use case.